# Orm error on tinyint

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have the following mapping:

```
<cfcomponent persistent="true" cacheuse="nonstrict-read-write"> 
    <cfproperty name="sourcetypeid" fieldtype="id" generator="identity"> 
    ...
```

The data field is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SourceType](
    [SourceTypeID] [tinyint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ...
```

I get the following error when I try to commit changes

```
unrecognized id type : byte -> java.lang.Byte
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSB7BEC0B4-8096-498d-8F9B-77C88878AC6C.html#WS96547CBD-E218-4a3a-94C5-35081A7C8B61), byte is not a supported ormtype.  The closest would be `short`.

Can you try this?

```
<cfproperty name="sourcetypeid" 
       fieldtype="id" 
       ormtype="short"  
       generator="identity">
```

Comment: Yep, just had the same thought myself ;-) `short` should work. If not also try `integer`.